# Horizontal and vertical scrolling?

Tags: java, android

I have a dynamic grid and my thing is that the User can zoom in and out, to left and right, up and down too view other elements from the Grid. How can I make that?
With the Basic gridviews the User can only scroll down but I need a solution to scroll all directions.

Comment: Can you provide some samples?

Comment: You must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).